# pouchdb not getting attachments with query()

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

I have a design view named **_design/templates** like so (getting all docs that have a specific type):

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.type == "template")
    emit(doc._id, doc);
}
```

I then go and grab the view with a query:

```
db.query('templates',{ 
    include_docs: true,
    attachments: true
})
.then(function (result) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
});
```

The result shows me the attachments but doesn't give me the `data` attribute with the actual base64 data of my images.

```
"_attachments":{
  "page_2.png":{
    "content_type":"image/png",
    "revpos":3,
    "digest":"md5-UHICp3Zi90ZVNMzyTUqRkQ==",
    "length":1917411,
    "stub":true
  },
  "page_1.png":{
    "content_type":"image/png",
    "revpos":2,
    "digest":"md5-GTXsZlsMa+NwZQDjJNMVAw==",
    "length":492139,
    "stub":true
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this would happen?

Comment: First, never emit the doc as a value(since include_docs) basically returns you the full doc. Second, can you explain what you mean by not getting the data? What is the data for you? (Doc's values, attachments, etc)

Comment: Understood, only just found out `include_docs` was technically required to get attachments. I should be getting a `data` attribute with my `_attachments` that actual gives me the base64 of my image but I only get the listed attachments (see revised question) @AlexisCôté

Comment: Seems like you get the result of a query wich attachments to false (wich is weird). If you query your attachment with the get() function, do you get the data?

Comment: Very weird indeed. Just checked and I get the data if I use get() or allDocs() while using the attachments option @AlexisCôté

Comment: Maybe the view is the problem. What if you do a simple view that do this : emit(doc._id); Then query it with the attachments

Comment: Also, back in the days, this was not implemented yet (See [this link](https://github.com/pouchdb/pouchdb/issues/3023)). I don't know if it's implemented yet or if you use a old version of PouchDB

Comment: Wow the simple view of `emit(doc._id);` worked! Youdaman!!! I wonder why that is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@AlexisCôté helped me with this. Because I'm already retrieving the document with `include_docs`, I changed my view from:

this:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.type == "template")
    emit(doc._id, doc);
}
```

to this:

```
function (doc) {
  if(doc.type == "template")
    emit(doc._id);
}
```